# XSL multiple conditions greater than 0

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have an XSL if that used work. TThe field in the table was defaulted to NULL.  Some how they changed it on me and now it is defaulted to 0.0   Now my XSL is not working and I have been trying for days to figure out why.  Sometimes choiceA or choiceB can be 0.whatevernumber

```
<xsl:if test="not(@choiceA = '0') or not(@choiceB = '0')">  
<h2 class="course-heading">Big list of choiceA and choiceB</h2>
    <span class="choice list-sq">
    <ul>
    <xsl:if test="not(@choiceA = '0')">
    <li><xsl:value-of select="@choiceA"/>&#160;choiceAs</li>
    </xsl:if>   
    </ul>
    </span>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: It's not clear from your question what is considered working or not.
Try to give the source XML and indicate the results that are expected and the results you are getting.

Comment: @JRQ I guess my question is more like this.. I used to be able to get the values if they were NULL, but not now.  They are no longer NULL, they are 0.0 and I don't want them to display if they are 0.0, BUT I do want them to display if they are 0.5, etc.. does that make sense?

Comment: I would switch to a numeric comparison, which will exclude NULL, 0, 0.0 from the match. i.e. @choiceA>0